# Как копировать блок адсенс (html + стили)

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте,
необходимо сделать такой же блок для сайта, но через исходный код выдает java, а мне нужен html + css для своих нужд, как собственно копировать?

пример на сайте [Пример](http://download-software.ru/google-chrome.html)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```css
div,
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.abgc {
  display: block;
  height: 15px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  width: 15px;
  z-index: 9020;
}

.abgb {
  display: block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}

.abgc img {
  display: block;
}

.abgc svg {
  display: block;
}

.abgs {
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
}

.abgl {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.abgi {
  fill-opacity: 1.0;
  fill: #00aecd;
  stroke: none;
}

.abgbg {
  fill-opacity: 1.0;
  fill: #cdcccc;
  stroke: none;
}

.abgtxt {
  fill: black;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 100px;
  overflow: visible;
  stroke: none;
}

.abgac {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 9100;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.grid-ad-box {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: block;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
  height: 190px;
  width: 355px;
}

.grid-container {
  height: 171px;
  width: 355px;
  display: table-row;
  display: inline-block;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.rows-1 .grid-container {
  display: table-cell;
  display: inline-block;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.grid-attribution {
  width: 355px;
  height: 19px;
  display: table-row;
  display: inline-block;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: top;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.rows-1 .grid-attribution {
  display: table-cell;
  display: inline-block;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-link-container {
  height: 42px;
  width: 355px;
  display: table;
  display: inline-block;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-top: -2px \9;
}

.grid-link-container:nth-child(n+5) {
  display: none;
}

.rows-1 .grid-link-container {
  display: table-cell;
  display: inline-block;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.rows-1 .grid-link-container {
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.grid-link {
  width: 95%;
  height: 90%;
  display: block;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 37px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35) inset, 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #0053f9;
  border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0053f9;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.rows-1 .grid-link {
  box-shadow: none;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
}

.columns-1 .grid-link {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
}

.grid-link:hover {
  background-color: #0053f9;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.alt,
.grid-link {
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.t>.alt,
body:not(.rows-1) .grid-link {
  border-left: #0053f9 solid 5px;
}

.al>.alt,
.rows-1 .grid-link {
  box-shadow: none;
  height: 188px;
  border: solid 1px #0053f9;
  border-left: solid 5px #0053f9;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-ad-box">
  <div class="grid-attribution">

    <div id="abgc" class="abgc" dir="ltr" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 109px; height: 15px;">
      <div id="abgb" class="abgb" style="display: none;">

        <svg width="100%" height="100%"><rect class="abgbg" width="100%" height="100%"></rect><svg class="abgi" x="0px"><path d="M7.5,1.5a6,6,0,1,0,0,12a6,6,0,1,0,0,-12m0,1a5,5,0,1,1,0,10a5,5,0,1,1,0,-10ZM6.625,11l1.75,0l0,-4.5l-1.75,0ZM7.5,3.75a1,1,0,1,0,0,2a1,1,0,1,0,0,-2Z"></path></svg></svg>
      </div>
      <div id="abgs" class="abgs" style="display: block;"><a id="abgl" class="abgl" href="https://www.google.com/url?ct=abg&amp;q=https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/request.py%3Fcontact%3Dabg_afc%26url%3Dhttp://download-software.ru/google-chrome.html%26gl%3DRU%26hl%3Dru%26client%3Dca-pub-3885028166827484%26ai0%3DC-pRN6lZEWrfKJIu66wSmm4fgCv2-u7YFnbqB9NMBACDIlvgYYISN7YXsHcgBAagDAcgDAqoEoAFP0A7rXIbAVn07SK0Pt2zI9uXp8-toT8o2I0e0ZrleCv_3ED9JllCQetp3aHvZYdYwLrKkBZVKJaHUkLyihIZAJ_hA9UDYvJv1qlUFXYkaN731ZHPP9PrExpP4VWuKFMMdCB_wGICYN56GAZB65fd1mKdaSs8LLWGpOlX55PRljna-kB5nWNLyqh-01v4p95YWLFxJWuzqEQmRPY2QB3fwoAZLqAemvhvYBwHSCAcIgGEQARgCgAoB&amp;usg=AFQjCNEdupgZSS9e3M1ZP1D_1QfT6HESmg"
          target="_blank"><svg width="100%" height="100%"><path class="abgbg" d="M0,0L109,0L109,11s0,4,-4,4L0,15z"></path><svg class="abgtxt" x="17px" y="11px" width="49px"><text transform="scale(0.0927810650887574)">Реклама от</text></svg><svg class="abgtxt" x="68px" y="11px" width="36px"><text transform="scale(0.11164142943670503)">Google</text></svg><svg class="abgi" x="0px"><path d="M7.5,1.5a6,6,0,1,0,0,12a6,6,0,1,0,0,-12m0,1a5,5,0,1,1,0,10a5,5,0,1,1,0,-10ZM6.625,11l1.75,0l0,-4.5l-1.75,0ZM7.5,3.75a1,1,0,1,0,0,2a1,1,0,1,0,0,-2Z"></path></svg></svg></a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="abgac" class="abgac" aria-hidden="true"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-link-container"><a href="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-3885028166827484&amp;output=html&amp;h=190&amp;w=355&amp;bih=962&amp;biw=1905&amp;slotname=7344304414&amp;adk=287151174&amp;url=http://download-software.ru/google-chrome.html&amp;frm=20&amp;eid=21061122,38893302,62710011,62710014,191880502&amp;loeid=38893312&amp;u_his=32&amp;u_nplug=3&amp;u_nmime=4&amp;brdim=1920,26,1920,26,1920,0,1920,1028,1920,962&amp;prev_fmts=355x190_0ads_al&amp;format=fpkc_al_lp&amp;kw_type=radlink&amp;hl=ru&amp;rt=ChBaRFbqAApWXwqa3ZGXCM6bEgEgGgi-oYZI-6TeoygBUhMIt-f0udSr2AIVC92aCh2mzQGseAGCARkKFdCh0LrQsNGH0LDRgtGMIGNocm9tZRIAggEnCiPQo9GB0YLQsNC90L7QstC40YLRjCDQsdGA0LDRg9C30LXRgBIAggEUChBHb29nbGUgY2hyb21lIDY0EgCCASUKIdCR0LXRgdC_0LvQsNGC0L3QviDRgdC60LDRh9Cw0YLRjBIAiAEA&amp;ad_type=text"
        class="grid-link" target="_blank" id="ala1"><span class="atp"></span>Скачать chrome<span class="ats"></span></a></div>
    <div class="grid-link-container"><a href="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-3885028166827484&amp;output=html&amp;h=190&amp;w=355&amp;bih=962&amp;biw=1905&amp;slotname=7344304414&amp;adk=287151174&amp;url=http://download-software.ru/google-chrome.html&amp;frm=20&amp;eid=21061122,38893302,62710011,62710014,191880502&amp;loeid=38893312&amp;u_his=32&amp;u_nplug=3&amp;u_nmime=4&amp;brdim=1920,26,1920,26,1920,0,1920,1028,1920,962&amp;prev_fmts=355x190_0ads_al&amp;format=fpkc_al_lp&amp;kw_type=radlink&amp;hl=ru&amp;rt=ChBaRFbqAApWXwqa3ZGXCM6bEgEgGgi-oYZI-6TeoygBUhMIt-f0udSr2AIVC92aCh2mzQGseAGCARkKFdCh0LrQsNGH0LDRgtGMIGNocm9tZRIAggEnCiPQo9GB0YLQsNC90L7QstC40YLRjCDQsdGA0LDRg9C30LXRgBIAggEUChBHb29nbGUgY2hyb21lIDY0EgCCASUKIdCR0LXRgdC_0LvQsNGC0L3QviDRgdC60LDRh9Cw0YLRjBIAiAEB&amp;ad_type=text"
        class="grid-link" target="_blank" id="ala2"><span class="atp"></span>Установить браузер<span class="ats"></span></a></div>
    <div class="grid-link-container"><a href="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-3885028166827484&amp;output=html&amp;h=190&amp;w=355&amp;bih=962&amp;biw=1905&amp;slotname=7344304414&amp;adk=287151174&amp;url=http://download-software.ru/google-chrome.html&amp;frm=20&amp;eid=21061122,38893302,62710011,62710014,191880502&amp;loeid=38893312&amp;u_his=32&amp;u_nplug=3&amp;u_nmime=4&amp;brdim=1920,26,1920,26,1920,0,1920,1028,1920,962&amp;prev_fmts=355x190_0ads_al&amp;format=fpkc_al_lp&amp;kw_type=radlink&amp;hl=ru&amp;rt=ChBaRFbqAApWXwqa3ZGXCM6bEgEgGgi-oYZI-6TeoygBUhMIt-f0udSr2AIVC92aCh2mzQGseAGCARkKFdCh0LrQsNGH0LDRgtGMIGNocm9tZRIAggEnCiPQo9GB0YLQsNC90L7QstC40YLRjCDQsdGA0LDRg9C30LXRgBIAggEUChBHb29nbGUgY2hyb21lIDY0EgCCASUKIdCR0LXRgdC_0LvQsNGC0L3QviDRgdC60LDRh9Cw0YLRjBIAiAEC&amp;ad_type=text"
        class="grid-link" target="_blank" id="ala3"><span class="atp"></span>Google chrome 64<span class="ats"></span></a></div>
    <div class="grid-link-container"><a href="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-3885028166827484&amp;output=html&amp;h=190&amp;w=355&amp;bih=962&amp;biw=1905&amp;slotname=7344304414&amp;adk=287151174&amp;url=http://download-software.ru/google-chrome.html&amp;frm=20&amp;eid=21061122,38893302,62710011,62710014,191880502&amp;loeid=38893312&amp;u_his=32&amp;u_nplug=3&amp;u_nmime=4&amp;brdim=1920,26,1920,26,1920,0,1920,1028,1920,962&amp;prev_fmts=355x190_0ads_al&amp;format=fpkc_al_lp&amp;kw_type=radlink&amp;hl=ru&amp;rt=ChBaRFbqAApWXwqa3ZGXCM6bEgEgGgi-oYZI-6TeoygBUhMIt-f0udSr2AIVC92aCh2mzQGseAGCARkKFdCh0LrQsNGH0LDRgtGMIGNocm9tZRIAggEnCiPQo9GB0YLQsNC90L7QstC40YLRjCDQsdGA0LDRg9C30LXRgBIAggEUChBHb29nbGUgY2hyb21lIDY0EgCCASUKIdCR0LXRgdC_0LvQsNGC0L3QviDRgdC60LDRh9Cw0YLRjBIAiAED&amp;ad_type=text"
        class="grid-link" target="_blank" id="ala4"><span class="atp"></span>Бесплатно скачать<span class="ats"></span></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```